# Getting Running Script Names Via PS

Tags: linux, grep, ps

I need to get a list of all running PHP scripts but piping PS thru  grep just gives me a list of all references to PHP files

How do I accomplish this? Is this even possible?

```
root@myhost:/var/www/cron/jobs# ps -ef | grep *.php | grep -v grep
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the command you need:

```
ps -ef | grep '[\.]php'
```

Of course, this will find anything containing ".php", e.g. PHP files opened in an editor, too.

Answer (score 0):

If run with php cli:

```
    ps -C php
```